# Virtual Host directs me to Xampp dashboard

Tags: php, apache, networking, server, xampp

I am trying to run my website on different devices.

I have this in my **httpd-vhosts.confiq**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have uncommented out the hash's that were in the file before changing them.

in my **hosts files:**

```
192.168.56.1           mywebsite.com
```

My website folder is like so:

```
Mywebsite
    - Home
        -about 
        -blog
        -profile
    - index.php
    - login
        -login.php
    - connections
        -connections.php
```

so these are the folders with some of the files inside.

Now when i restart apache and type the following:

`http://mywebsite.com`

it directs me to `http://mywebsite.com/dashboard` which is just a xampp webpage.

Why does this occur?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full configution I can only guess but I suggest you to start changing

```
<VirtualHost VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```